# Heroku CLI - How to solve the Error: Missing required flag: -a --app APP?

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

I manage to deploy a Scala Play 2.7 App that uses Postgres but it doesn't run with error:

```
(base) bravegag@Zeus:~/code/myapp$ heroku open
 ›   Error: Missing required flag:
 ›     -a, --app APP  app to run command against
 ›   See more help with --help
(base) bravegag@Zeus:~/code/myapp$ heroku logs --tail
 ›   Error: Missing required flag:
 ›     -a, --app APP  app to run command against
 ›   See more help with --help
```

How do I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's a heroku cli flag, not scala/play. just specify the name of your heroku app when using the heroku cli:

```
$ heroku open --app <app-name>
```

(same for other commands)

you can find the name of your app in heroku dashboard (somewhere in https://heroku.com)

If you enter your app in heroku you will reach a link like `https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/<app-name>`

Comment: you pointed me to the right direction +1

Answer (score 2):

you need to set git remote to your application first, or heroku won't detect your flags,

```
heroku git:remote -a your_app_name
```

Answer (score 1):

first you need to initialize git (which is required for Heroku)

```
    $ git init
    $ git add .
    $ git commit -m "first"
```

then you should

```
    $ heroku git:remote -a your_app_name
```

and then finally you can:

```
    $ heroku container:push web
```